# Code Golf: Shortest code to find a weighted median?

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf

My try at code golfing.

The problem of [finding the minimum value of `∑W_i*|X-X_i|`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964826/how-to-compute-the-minimum-value-of-wix-xi) reduces to finding the weighted median of a list of `x[i]` with weights `w[i]` (see below for definition). How will you do that with a shortest, simplest and most beautiful program?

Here's how my code looked originally (explanation is in [the answer to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964826?sort=votes#sort-top) and short version is posted as one of the answers below).

```
    #define zero(x) ( abs(x) < 1e-10 )  /* because == doesn't work for floats */

    float sum = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
         sum += w[i];
    while (sum > 0) 
         sum -= 2*w[--i];

    right = x[i]             // the rightmost minimum point
    left  = ( zero(sum) && zero(w[i]-w[i-1]) ) ? x[i-1] : right;
    answer = (left + right) / 2;
```

(Actually, it's been already heavily optimized as you see variables `i` and `sum` reused)

### Rules

**Floats and integers:** different languages have different floating point arithmetic standards, so I reformulate the problem to have `x[i]` and `w[i]` to be **integers** and you can return twice the value of the answer (which is always integer) if you prefer. You can return, print or assign the answer to variable.

**Definition of weighted median and clarifications:**

- Median of sorted array `x[i]` of length `n` is either `x[n/2]` or `(x[n/2-1/2]+x[n/2+1/2])/2` depending  on whether `n` is odd or even
- <s>Median of unsorted array is the median of array after sort</s> (true, but our array is sorted)
- Weighted median of `x[i]` with integer positive weights `w[i]` is defined as the median of larger array where each occurrence of `x[i]` has been changed into `w[i]` occurrences of `x[i]`.

### What I hope to see

One of the reasons for asking is that I assume the most suitable language will have trivial array summation and iteration with lambdas. I thought a functional language could be reasonable, but I'm not sure about that - so it's part of the question. My hope is to see something like

```
    // standard function   add  :=  (a,b) :-> a + b 
    myreduce := w.reduce  
        with:  add  
        until: (value) :-> 2*value >= (w.reduce with:add)
    answer = x [myreduce  from:Begin] + x [myreduce  from:End]
```

Dunno if there's any language where this is possible and is actually shorter.

### Test data

```
static int n = 10;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        w[j] = j + 1;
        x[j] = j;
}
```

Answer: 6 or 12.

```
static int n = 9;
int w[n], x[n] ;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    w[j] = j + ((j<6) ? 1 : 0);
    x[j] = j + 1;
}
```

Answer: 6.5 or 13.

Comment: [functional-programming] Inigo Montoya says "You keep using that word. I do no think it means what you think it means."

Comment: ... can you make your code a little more readable?

Comment: Code golf questions should be CW.

Comment: Clarified that x[i] is sorted. BTW, what is CW?

Comment: You can still change it to community wiki (I think).

Comment: Did it! Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Yeah sample data would be great.

Comment: @dmckee: I clarified what I meant by functional programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/)

Go ahead and type this directly into the interpreter.  The prompt is three spaces, so the indented lines are user input.

```
   m=:-:@+/@(((2*+/\)I.+/)"1@(,:(\:i.@#))@[{"0 1(,:(\:i.@#))@])
```

The test data I used in my other answer:

```
   1 1 1 1 m 1 2 3 4
2.5
   1 1 2 1 m 1 2 3 4
3
   1 2 2 5 m 1 2 3 4
3.5
   1 2 2 6 m 1 2 3 4
4
```

The test data added to the question:

```
   (>:,:[)i.10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9
   (>:m[)i.10
6
   (([+<&6),:>:)i.9
1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   (([+<&6)m>:)i.9
6.5
```

---

```
   i =: (2 * +/\) I. +/
```

First index such that total sum is greater than or equal to double the accumulated sum.

```
   j =: ,: (\: i.@#)
```

List and its reverse.

```
   k =: i"1 @ j @ [
```

First indices such that *-see above-* of the left argument and its reverse.

```
   l =: k {"(0 1) j @ ]
```

Those indices extracted from the right argument and its reverse, respectively.

```
   m =: -: @ +/ @ l
```

Half the sum of the resulting list.

Comment: Cool, very much what I wanted. There's something wrong with the Newton's method: the answer should always be half-integer.

Comment: Hmm, it appears that comparisons are quite long. If there's a simple way to flop the array, it could be easier to find j in the same way as i but from the other side. Then (x[i]+x[j])/2 is always an answer (actually, x[i]+x[j] is a good answer since I modified the rules to stay within integers).

Also, I give up on this one: why is the function with two arguments defined with 4 and 0?

Comment: Never mind about m =:4 :0, I read how that's just a syntax for dyads.

Comment: Still, could the third line be made shorter, like second?

Comment: A change in strategy, so now there's only one line :)

Answer (score 3):

So, here's how I could squeeze my own solution:, still leaving some whitespaces:

```
    int s = 0, i = 0;
    for (; i < n; s += w[i++]) ;
    while ( (s -= 2*w[--i] ) > 0) ;
    a  =  x[i]  +  x[ !s && (w[i]==w[i-1]) ? i-1 : i ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Haskell code, ungolfed: trying for a reasonable functional solution.

```
import Data.List (zip4)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

mid :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> (Int, Bool)
mid w = (i, total == part && maybe False (l ==) r) where
    (i, l, r, part):_ = dropWhile less . zip4 [0..] w v $ map (2*) sums
    _:sums = scanl (+) 0 w; total = last sums; less (_,_,_,x) = x < total
    v = map Just w ++ repeat Nothing

wmedian :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> (a, Maybe a)
wmedian w x = (left, if rem then listToMaybe rest else Nothing) where
    (i, rem) = mid w; left:rest = drop i x
```

```
> wmedian [1,1,1,1] [1,2,3,4]
(2,Just 3)
> wmedian [1,1,2,1] [1,2,3,4]
(3,Nothing)
> wmedian [1,2,2,5] [1,2,3,4]
(3,Just 4)
> wmedian [1,2,2,6] [1,2,3,4]
(4,Nothing)
```

```
> wmedian [1..10] [0..9]
(6,Nothing)
> wmedian ([1..6]++[6..8]) [1..9]
(6,Just 7)
```

---

My original J solution was a straightforward translation of the above Haskell code.

Here's a Haskell translation of the current J code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}
import Data.List (find); import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
w&x=foldr((+).fst.fromJust.find((>=sum w).snd))0[f.g(+)0$map
    (2*)w|f<-[zip x.tail,reverse.zip x]|g<-[scanl,scanr]]/2
```

Yeah… please don't write code like this.

```
> [1,1,1,1]&[1,2,3,4]
2.5
> [1,1,2,1]&[1,2,3,4]
3
> [1,2,2,5]&[1,2,3,4]
3.5
> [1,2,2,6]&[1,2,3,4]
4
> [1..10]&[0..9]
6
> ([1..6]++[6..8])&[1..9]
6.5
```

Comment: Looks interesting, I'm parsing it... (I actually wrote I wanted to see some Haskell from the start, but was snubbed by functional languages crowd, so removed the idea...)

Answer (score 2):

short, and does what you'd expect. Not particularly space-efficient.

```
def f(l,i):
   x,y=[],sum(i)
   map(x.extend,([m]*n for m,n in zip(l,i)))
   return (x[y/2]+x[(y-1)/2])/2.
```

here's the constant-space version using itertools. it still has to iterate sum(i)/2 times so it won't beat the index-calculating algorithms.

```
from itertools import *
def f(l,i):
   y=sum(i)-1
   return sum(islice(
       chain(*([m]*n for m,n in zip(l,i))),
       y/2,
       (y+1)/2+1
   ))/(y%2+1.)
```

Comment: Yes, using sum(i) amount of space might be an overkill... maybe in the future python arrays will be smart enough to not allocate the space?

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
a=sum([[X]*W for X,W in zip(x,w)],[]);l=len(a);a[l/2]+a[(l-1)/2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? O(n) running time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
sum += x[i] * w[i];
sums.push(sum);
}

median = sum/2;

for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
{
    if(median > sums[element] and median < sums[element+1]
         return x[i];
    if(median == sums[element])
         return (x[i] + x[i+1])/2
}
```

Not sure how you can get two answers for the median, do you mean if sum/2 is exactly equal to a boundary?

EDIT: After looking at your formatted code, my code does essentially the same thing, did you want a MORE efficient method?

EDIT2: The search part can be done using a modified binary search, that would make it slightly faster.

```
index = sums.length /2;
finalIndex = binarySearch(index);

int binarySearch(i)
{
    if(median > sums[i+1])
    {
        i += i/2
        return binarySearch(i);
    }
    else if(median < sums[i])
    {
        i -= i/2
        return binarySearch(i);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Will have to do some checking to make sure it doesn't go on infinitely on edge cases.

Comment: In my understanding of the tradition of code golfing, I was thinking about the shortest program. That's why mine reuses variables suma nd i for two cycles :)

Comment: Are you looking for shortest or fastest?

Comment: Shortest! Anyway, your code and mine appears to be identical as for performance, and in general it's not possible to compare performance in different languages beyond O(...)

Comment: yeah, it's going to have to be O(n) because of the sum, let me rethink this about writing it shorter, though... not really a practical reason for doing that.

Comment: All of solutions, including yours, will be likely O(n).

Comment: Exactly, your algorithmic complexity is not helped by the binary search at all because the function as a whole is already O(n).

Answer (score -5):

Just a comment about your code : I really hope I will not have to maintain it, unless you also wrote all the unit tests that are required here :-)

It is not related to your question of course, but usually, the "shortest way to code" is also the "hardest way to maintain". For scientific applications, it is probably not a show stopper. But for IT applications, it is.

I think it has to be said. All the best.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I wrote a long answer to somebody else's question (my answer is also linked now) and tried to write a very readable code. But now I'm thinking about code golfing, so I am also trying to produce a minimum version.

Comment: @Sylvain - the point of code golf isn't to produce production-quality code. It's more like a brain-teaser - fun and challenging, but not to be used to real life projects.