# is Boost Library's weighted median broken?

Tags: c++, boost, statistics

I confess that I am no expert in C++.

I am looking for a fast way to compute weighted median, which Boost seemed to have.
But it seems I am not able to make it work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/median.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/weighted_median.hpp>
using namespace boost::accumulators;    

int main()
{
  // Define an accumulator set
  accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::median > > acc1;
  accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::median >, float> acc2;

  // push in some data ...
  acc1(0.1);
  acc1(0.2);
  acc1(0.3);
  acc1(0.4);
  acc1(0.5);
  acc1(0.6);

  acc2(0.1, weight=0.);
  acc2(0.2, weight=0.);
  acc2(0.3, weight=0.);
  acc2(0.4, weight=1.);
  acc2(0.5, weight=1.);
  acc2(0.6, weight=1.);

  // Display the results ...
  std::cout << "         Median: " << median(acc1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Weighted Median: " << median(acc2) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

produces the following output, which is clearly wrong.

```
         Median: 0.3
Weighted Median: 0.3
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

*** however, the weighted sum works correctly ***

@glowcoder: The weighted sum works perfectly fine like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/sum.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/weighted_sum.hpp>
using namespace boost::accumulators;

int main()
{
  // Define an accumulator set
  accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::sum > > acc1;
  accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::sum >, float> acc2;
  // accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::median >, float> acc2;

  // push in some data ...
  acc1(0.1);
  acc1(0.2);
  acc1(0.3);
  acc1(0.4);
  acc1(0.5);
  acc1(0.6);

  acc2(0.1, weight=0.);
  acc2(0.2, weight=0.);
  acc2(0.3, weight=0.);
  acc2(0.4, weight=1.);
  acc2(0.5, weight=1.);
  acc2(0.6, weight=1.);

  // Display the results ...
  std::cout << "         Median: " << sum(acc1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Weighted Median: " << sum(acc2) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

and the result is

```
         Sum: 2.1
Weighted Sum: 1.5
```

Answer (score 5):

The boost function is not broken.

The problem is that you do not provide enough data for the P^2 estimator to work. If you put a loop around your data input such as

```
for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
  acc2(0.1, weight=0.);
  acc2(0.2, weight=0.);
  acc2(0.3, weight=0.);
  acc2(0.4, weight=1.);
  acc2(0.5, weight=1.);
  acc2(0.6, weight=1.);
}
```

you get the correct result of

```
Median: 0.3
Weighted Median: 0.5
```

alternatively, you can specify

```
 accumulator_set<double, 
    stats<tag::weighted_median(with_p_square_cumulative_distribution) >, 
    double> acc2 ( p_square_cumulative_distribution_num_cells = 5 );
```

which gives `Weighted Median: 0.55` as an answer even with only 6 points added as in your question.

Answer (score 3):

What is weighted median supposed to mean? A median considers only the order of the items, not the content. A weight doesn't change the order (it can change the mean or the sum though). If you used occurence counts (natural integers) instead of floats, you could extend the definition of the median, but I don't think that's what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Weighted median a^* (of samples x_1,x_2,...,x_N given weights w_1,w_2,...,w_N) is defined as a^* = arg_a min sum_{k=1}{N} w_k |x_k-a|

Comment: You can also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966896/code-golf-shortest-code-to-find-a-weighted-median

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::weighted_median(with_weighted_density) >, float> acc2;
```

Comment: I think that method wants arguments which is a probability density. I want to manually specify weights

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation, it says it uses the P^2 estimator for calculating the median. I did a google search and found Jain & Chlamtac "*The P^2 algorithm for dynamic calculation of quantiles and histograms without storing observations*".  To my surprise it seems to me Boost Accumulator's median is only an estimate not the exact value.  It should have been called median_est instead of median.

And it does really seem as if weighted median is broken; it doesn't take weights into account.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calling median twice. Perhaps you meant to call weighted_median the second time?

Comment: Thanks, but the doc says that if weights are non-void, the calculation is done with the weighted counterpart.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_accumulators_framework.weighted_samples