# How to neglect the output of OCR Engine that has no meaning?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, ocr, tesseract

Tesseract OCR engine sometimes outputs text that has no meaning, i want to design an algorithm  that neglects any text or word that has no meaning, below is some sort of output text that i want to neglect,my simple solution is to count the words in the recognized text that's separated by " " and the text which has too many words will be garbage(Hint: i'm scanning images which at most will contains 40 words) any idea will be helpful,thanks.

```
 wo:>"|axnoA1wvw\
 ldﬂﬁg
 °J!9O‘ !P99W M9N 6 13!-|15!Cl ‘I-/Vl
 978 89l9 Z0 3+ 3 'l9.l.
 97 999 VLL lLOZ+ 3 9l!q°lN
 wo0'|axno/(@|au1e>1e: new;
 1=96r2a1ey\1 1uauud0|e/\e(]
 |8UJB){ p8UJL|\7'
```

Comment: Very broad question. First, how do you know if a text or a word has no meaning? (i.e. do you have a perfect dictionary?). How do you account for local mistakes? Eg. If 'ENGINE' is read as 'ENGTINE' do you discard it completely? I can go on and on.

Comment: You could look for too many consecutive symbols, or consecutive letter combinations that do not occur in the language of the text, on top of looking at word length. 1-3 letter words are not likely to be misspelled or from another language, so dictionary could help for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the output text into words.  Divide the words into triples.  Count the triple frequencies, and compare to triple frequencies from text of a known-good text corpus (EG all the articles from some mailing list discussing what you intend to OCR, minus the header lines).

When I say "triples", I mean:

whe, hen, i, say, tri, rip, ipl, ple, les, i, mea, ean

...so "i" has a frequency of 2 in this short example, while the others are all frequency 1.

If you do a frequency count of each of these triples for a large document in your intended language, it should become possible to be reasonably accurate in guessing whether a string is in the same language.

Granted, it's heuristic.

I've used a similar approach for detecting English passwords in a password changing program.  It worked pretty well, though there's no such thing as a perfect "obvious password rejecter".

Comment: These "triples" are properly called trigrams.

Answer (score 1):

Check the words against a dictionary?

Of course, this will have false-positives for things like foreign-phrases or code.  The problem in general is intractable *(ex. is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/967906/238419) code or gibberish? :) )*.  The only (nearly) perfect method would be to use this as a heuristic to flag certain sections for human review.